# Shortest Code to Translate a PHP array

Tags: code-golf, tips, array, php

### NOTE: This question was migrated from https://stackoverflow.com/q/27134588/1442685

PHP QUESTION

Almost purely out of curiousity, how can I take an array like this:

```
array( 'fruit' => 'banana', 'drink' => 'milk')
```

And convert it to an array like this:

```
array( 'fruit=banana', 'drink=milk')
```

**Requirements**

- Cannot use anonymous functions
- If needed, can only use `array_*` functions that accept callable if that callable is native to PHP
- Must be a one-liner solution

---

This is not for a class. I'm curious to see how clever one can be with array functions. Given the requirements, is it possible?

Comment: Hello, welcome to PPCG :) Presumably, you want the shortest code to do this? If so, I recommend tagging your problem [tag:code-golf] (Currently this lacks a winning criterion and could be closed). Consider using our [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for future questions.

Comment: Thanks @FryAmTheEggman - I've updated my tag, and am reading up on the sandbox now.

Comment: No problem :) Just some nit-picking, you might want to edit your title to reflect the rules i.e. "Shortest Code to translate a PHP array." You also shouldn't say "preferably"; either force one-liners, or don't. Also, just like SO, wait a while before accepting ;p

Comment: Got it. Will do.

Comment: This question isn't migrated: it's cross-posted, and it's already been answered on SO.

Comment: Yea, I don't know how to do that/I don't have authority to. How do suggest I handle this?

Comment: If you want to migrate a question from one site to another within the Stack Exchange network, you should use a custom flag. But 99% of the time you should pay no attention to people on SO who say that a question would be a better fit on PPCG, because most of them have no idea what's on topic here and what isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
explode('&',http_build_query($a))
```

33 bytes

Comment: PHP actually has an `explode` function? Cool. :D

Comment: By the way, since this is code-golf, you should update your answer with the [length of your code in bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#explode%28%27%26%27%2C%20http%5fbuild%5fquery%28%24array%29%29). Also, I think you can remove that space character ;)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman.  Thanks, it looks like vBuck modified it for me.  New to codegolf, just copied my answer from SO tbh. :)

Comment: `split` is one character shorter than `explode` (not the same, but in this case functionally equivalent).

Comment: @Devon Whenever you copy your answer from somewhere else, you should always give credit to the original source. Could you edit that in?

Comment: @isaacg, I copied it from myself lol.

Comment: @primo, split is deprecated as of 5.3

Comment: @Devon `E_DEPRECATED` is of no consequence to code golf.

Comment: @primo, okay Thanks, I think I'm understanding how this site works now.

Comment: Note that `http_build_query()` will encode special characters like `&`. http://rextester.com/ZFSIX69274

Answer (score 5):

## PHP (33 bytes)

I am not 100% sure if this is valid.

I used 0 (**zero**) functions.

This solution is 1 byte shorter than @Devon's solution.

The code:

```
foreach($a as$k=>$v)$z[]="$k=$v";
```

The var `$a` is the array, the var `$z` will have the new array.

There are no restrictions to the vars or how it should be implemented.

Comment: Nice solution. It *does* work, but @Devon's answer still takes the cake on the following grounds: 1). Easier to read; 2). It's truly a 'one-liner' solution, where your solution requires multiple lines to implement -- ie: foreach cannot be evaluated as part of an expression, and the addition of `$z` requires another line for assignment or use.

Comment: I totally disagree with point 2. PHP is a free-form language (most of the whitespace don't matter) and the braces are optional for 1 expression. And the `foreach` can be implemented as an expression using `eval('foreach($a as$k=>$v)$z[]="$k=$v";return$z;');`, but DO NOT USE THIS NO MATTER WHAT! But still, I wasn't expecting to win this one: I just wanted to show another solution. But mine as the advantage of keeping a copy of the old array.

Comment: Hmm, well that's a clever way to evaluate a loop. I'll give you that much :) If memory footprint was a requirement, I wonder how the loop + 2 arrays would stack against the consumption of @Devon's code.

Comment: @vBuck It will consume around +1kb than the other solution. But nothing serious. About cpu cycles, mine probably would be a tiny mini bit faster. The overhead of calling 2 functions + looking for a substring + storing it's multiple parts and so on vs. a single iteration over 2 keys.

Answer (score 1):

## 32 bytes

```
foreach($a as$k=>&$v)$v="$k=$v";
```

Update by reference, shaves off 1 byte.

Not sure how important removing the original key is, sort of a grey area.

This is what I mean:

```
[
    ['fruit'] => 'fruit=banana',
    ['drink'] => 'drink=milk'
]
```

But it saves on variables, as your not creating a new array